# how to write many to many with 3 core table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, model, migration

I have class tables and lessons (many to many).

if the user can have many classes and many lessons. what is a user (many to many) with classes. then the user (many to many) with lessons?

how to get values ​​like:
George, 12th grade Senior High School, mathematics. ? (username, class_name, and lesson_name). in blade or controller.

please correct me if i wrong, im new in programming Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can i do it like this?

I made it into 4 tables.
1 tb_user, 2 tb_class, 3 tb_lesson, and 4 tb_details.

tb_user hasMany tb_detail
tb_detail belongsTo tb_class
tb_detail belongs To tb_ lesson

with that i hope i can get data like in my question with accessing the tb_detail.
please correct me if i wrong. im new in programming

Comment: oke its work.. but if this is not the best way, please someone correct me